# How to use regex to remove everything except certain "key"/"character containing"

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

Running my code gives me this output in a txt file:

```
19:27:28.636  ASSOS\032AB5601\0223-\032312DEEE8EB423._http._tcp.local. can
be reached at ASSOS-032DEEE8EB423.local.:80 (interface 1)
```

So I just want to parse out string "ASSOS-032DEEE8EB423.local" and remove everything else from the txt file. I can't figure out how to use regex to do so to remove everything except string containing ASSOS-. So the thing is that the string will always contain ASSOS- but the rest is always changing to different numbers. So I'm trying to always be able to get ASSOS-XXXXXXXXXXX.local

This is how I'm trying to do:

```
$string = 'Get-Content C:\MyFile.Txt' 
$pattern = '' 
$string -replace $pattern, ' '
```

It's just that I don't know so much about regex and how to write it to parse out string containing "ASSOS-" and remove everything after ASSOS-XXXXXXXXXXX.local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pipe the file content to `Select-String` and return the values of matches for a string starting with `"ASSOS-"`, ending with `"local"` and having whatever non-whitespace characters in between:

```
Get-Content test.txt |  Select-String -Pattern "ASSOS-\S*local" | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Value}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
$str = "19:27:28.636  ASSOS\032AB5601\0223-\032312DEEE8EB423._http._tcp.local. can
be reached at **ASSOS-032DEEE8EB423.local**.:80 (interface 1)"

$str -replace '.*\*\*(.*?)\*\*.*', '$1'
```

The `RegEx` `.*\*\*(.*?)\*\*.*` captures all characters within `**...**`. The `*` have to be escaped by a `\` to make it work.

Comment: My bad, I just saw that ** symbols are not in the text, I just edited the first post. Sorry for that!